# ffmpeg mosaic keep audio of all input videos

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have five videos and want to combine them into one big "strip" with all five videos next to each other.

My code so far (following [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos) example):

```
ffmpeg
    -i s-0-h-0.mp4 -i s-1-h-0.mp4 -i s-2-h-0.mp4 -i s-3-h-0.mp4 -i s-4-h-0.mp4
    -filter_complex "
        nullsrc=size=4240x478 [base];
        [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=848x478 [vid1];
        [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=848x478 [vid2];
        [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=848x478 [vid3];
        [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=848x478 [vid4];
        [4:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=848x478 [vid5];
        [base][vid1] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];
        [tmp1][vid2] overlay=shortest=1:x=848 [tmp2];
        [tmp2][vid3] overlay=shortest=1:x=1696 [tmp3];
        [tmp3][vid4] overlay=shortest=1:x=2544 [tmp4];
        [tmp4][vid5] overlay=shortest=1:x=3392
    "
   -c:v libx264 output.mkv
```

However, this only includes the audio from input 1.

How do I keep the audio of all five input videos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a]amix=5`

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm getting a _Too many inputs specified for the "amix" filter_ error when using more than two audio channels ([0:a][1:a]amix works). Am I correct to add it as the last item to filter_complex?

Comment: You can use hstack=5 instead of overlay, its much faster.